# Why is the base of the object fading in and out during rendering?

Tags: rendering

When I render an animation of my object (from motion tracking data) I am seeing the base fade in and out as shown in the two images below.
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? Here is the [.blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3pw00lmhvw0tut/Cabin.blend?dl=0) if that helps.

Comment: The 'fading' is actually just blurring from the vector blur node in the compositor. It's a bit hard to know how to solve this without knowing what the final effect you're looking for is.

Comment: Ah I see...I just want to render the animation so all frames look like the first image...should I just remove the vector blur node?

Comment: Yes, you can just remove it. I'll write up a full answer in a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'fading' is actually just blurring from the vector blur node in the compositor.

If you wish to remove this effect, you can either just disable the Vector Blur node by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> while the node is selected in the compositor to 'Mute' the node or you could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to essentially 'Cut' the node out. In future, you can use the technique of muting nodes one by one to diagnose issues with node setups.

If you remove the Vector Blur node you may be able to remove more nodes, such as the Alpha Over node the Vector Blur connects to and even the 'Foreground' render layer (as it may be the only purpose of this render layer is for the Vector Blur).